# Does using namespaces in every page a bad practice/ reduces performance or memory usage

Tags: c#, .net

In C# we write `using System.IO` or any other namespace we want to use.

So is it a bad habit, does it affect performance or memory?

Or is it good to create wrapper classes for them and use it to avoid using the same namespace everywhere?

Comment: @delnan that was very discouraging. someone didn't told u that no question is a dumb question. no idea doesn't mean that we should stop learning.

Comment: I'm all for learning. I just named topics to learn more about. As an added bonus, things like this become obvious when you learn them. You are right that my wording was harsh; what I meant to say was: If you don't know these things, *learn them* because they are required study *if* you want to ponder performance.

Comment: @delnan there are better ways to say this.

Comment: using are syntactic sugar. At the end, they won't appear in the generated IL. I imagine that if you could put a very large number of useless using in you files, you could negatively impact the compiler performance. But at the end, your program will run exactly the same, using or not.

Comment: @Sirwani Yes, my initial comment was worded too harshly. I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .Net, the namespace is always an integral part of the name of each type.
However, if you had to specify the entire namespace each time you are declaring a certain type it would have caused tremendous repetition and noise in the code. This is what the using directive is for, it essentially folds all the prefixes into one place, making you specify the "last" section of a type. This can be done only in case there are no ambiguities.

The compiler however, doesn't care about the above. So there exists a pre-compilation stage where each type declaration that relies on a `using` directive gets its prefix back.

So when you say:

```
Using System;

void foo()
{
   String s1 = "bla";
   String s2 = "bli";
}
```

What happens in pre-compilation is that the is appending the `System` namespace to each `String` declaration, like this:

```
void foo()
{
   System.String s1 = "bla";
   System.String s2 = "bli";
}
```

And only now the compiler really kicks in.

So about the performance, technically, it can effect performance of the build process. The more usings you have, the more matching needs to be done in the pre-compilation stage: so the compiler sees `String`. What `String` is that? Is it `System.String` or is it `SomeOtherNamespace.String`? What really happens is that the compiler appends each namespace it finds in using to the type declaration and checks whether such a type exists. If yes- great, if no- it trys the next namespace.

So you see, in case you have many files with unused `using` declarations, the compiler necessarily does redundant work. In extreme cases, it can significantly degrade the performance of the build itself.

In general, ***never hesitate Using something that you are using*** (no pun intended). But you should avoid declaring unnecessary `using` directives, not just because of the potential (unlikely) performance impact on the build duration but also because you want to keep your code as clean as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can have as many `using` statements at the top of the file as you like, it will not affect the runtime performance a bit.

Making wrappers for classes *will* however affect the performance, making the code slightly slower. Not by much, so you can very well use wrappers if it makes the code more managable, but using it just to avoid `using` statements is not a good reason.

Having a lot of `using` statements might affect the compilation time somewhat, but you would have to have *tons* of them before it would be noticable.

Consider using the "Remove unused usings" command in Visual Studio, which will remove the `using` statements for namespaces that are actually not used. I use it often, but just to keep the files lean, not for performance.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler does the optimization for us for including the related `assemblies of namespaces where required` so you do not need a wrapper for optimization. It is better to include all the namespace required by the class with `using statement on the top`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make using,  it's not important not affect your perfomance  (Best practise for your code is to delete using not used with right click)

Everything is loaded when it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

When you put using System.IO; in the beginning of the file you tell C# compiler to consider that namespace for class names lookup. It has no impact on program performance at all.

But if you create wrappers in the same file you will be creating additional (even it's small) copy of class for each class used and it will degrade performance at run time.